# usage of about before a range of numbers

Tags: adverbs

The business serves **10-15** clients per month.
or 
The business serves **about 10-15** clients per month.

Are the both sentences grammatically correct or the use of **about** is sensitive?

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences are grammatically correct. The one containing *about* is a little less precise.